# Using Collections method to sort something specific from a class

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, arraylist

Making an assignment and I've stumbled upon something I can't seem to fix nor properly seem to Google.

So I made a basic class like this with 3 attributes:

```
public class Planeet {
private int diameter;
private String naam;
private double relatieveMassa;

public Planeet(int diameter, String naam, double relatieveMassa) {
    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.naam = naam;
    this.relatieveMassa = relatieveMassa;
}}
```

Now I made another class where I made an ArrayList from the class above and it contains methods to print out the list in different kinds:

```
public class Planeten {
private List<Planeet> planeten = new ArrayList<Planeet>();

public void sorteer(){
    Collections.sort(??);
}}
```

Now my question is, how can I sort it on a specific attribute from my first class?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: Implement your own `Comparator` and pass it as an argument to `sort`.

Comment: Search for `Comparator`

Comment: ... or make Planet implement Compareable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a silly question, rather a newbish one. Please don't forget to include your getter(s) for the comparing fields (e.g. `naam` -> `getNaam()`).

```
public class PlaneetComparator implements Comparator<Planeet>
{
     @Override
     public int compare(final Planeet p1, final Planeet p2)
     {
           // Compare by names. Here, you can compare by any field you prefer.
           return p1.getNaam().compareToIgnoreCase( p2.getNaam() );
     }
}
```

After that:

```
Collections.sort(planeten, new PlaneetComparator());
```

**Keep in mind** this is just one way to do it. You could also use `Comparable<T>`, kudos to [A4L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113392/a4l).

Answer (score 1):

Just implement Comparable to your class end override the compareTo method. In the method just compare the property u want to be compared when the sorting is applied. 
Ex.

```
public class Planeet implements Comparable<Planeet>
private int diameter;
private String naam;
private double relatieveMassa;

public Planeet(int diameter, String naam, double relatieveMassa) {
    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.naam = naam;
    this.relatieveMassa = relatieveMassa;
}
 @Override
public int compareTo(Planeet arg0) {
    //sorting on naam
            return this.naam.compareTo(arg0.naam);
}
}
```

then in your other class just use

```
Collections.sort(planeten);
```

it will use the compareTo() method to sort them . If u want to make more sorting options, just make Comparators